API Gateway Private Domain fails to create using CloudFormation
I am creating Private Domain name for my API Gateway using following CFN snippet
ApiGatewayDomainName:  
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName  
Properties:  
  DomainName: "api.example.com"  
  CertificateArn: !Ref Certificate  
  EndpointConfiguration:  
    Types:  
      - PRIVATE

When I deploy code, the stack is stuck at "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS" state. I checked domain name creation in the API GW console and it is successfully created but in the end CFN deployment fails after approximately 30 minutes (CFN timeout?) with message Resource handler returned message: "null"

I tried to deploy REGIONAL DomainName using CFN without any issues. I also tried to deploy PRIVATE DomainName with same configuration as in CFN but manually using console and it also works.
Am i missing anything?

Could be many reasons. You haven't provided your API policy, haven't explained your VPC setup, nor even explained how you created the domain.

There is no need for API policy because the creation of DomainName is independent until you link it with API.
Creation of the domain is provided in the CFN snippet, manually I did the same.
It looks like since private domain name is new feature, CFN is not fully adapted.

Check cloud trail, it might have more information about the request cloudformation made and what went wrong

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-domainname-endpointconfiguration.html looks like PRIVATE should be supported
